# Detect Idle Time in React and JavaScript

Tags: react.js, timer, jsx

I'm creating a functionality that detects idle time for an app if there's no activity within an hour. It works ok but I'm not sure if the approach to handling inactivity is correct? and how do I make it reusable by making it into reusable hook? and should I place this in the `app.component`?

```
function App() {
  const [lastActive, setLastActive] = useState(new Date());
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [idleTime, setIdleTime] = useState(0);
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        const idle = currentTime - lastActive;

        if (idle > 3600000) {
          setIdleTime(idle);
          setOpen(true);

          const logoutInterval = setTimeout(() => {
            handleLogout();
          }, 60000);

          return () => clearTimeout(logoutInterval);
        }
      }, 3600000);

      return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, lastActive]);

  const handleUserActivity = () => {
    setLastActive(new Date());
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {

    console.log('User logged out due to inactivity');
    setOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUserActivity);
      document.addEventListener('keypress', handleUserActivity);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleUserActivity);
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', handleUserActivity);
      };
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  return (
    <>
      <Dialog open={open}>
        <DialogHeader>
          {' '}
          You&#39;ve been idle for {idleTime / 1000} seconds
        </DialogHeader>

        <DialogBody>
          <p>
            You&#39;ve been inactive for a while. To keep your session active,
            please click the button below or continue using the app
          </p>
        </DialogBody>
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button color='primary' variant='contained'>
            Keep Session Active
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How do you define inactivity? Is it exactly what you wrote in the code as having not moved mouse or pressed any key for certain time? Or, being user hasn't invoked any functions in the app for certain time?